# Jquery UI Sortable one directional

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have three `ul` say (`#ula`, `#ulb`, `#ulc`), and I want to use a jQueryUI Sortable on this so that I am able to drop items from `#ula` to either `#ulb` or `#ulc`.

My code working well, except for the issue that the items in `#ulb` are also draggable to `#ulc` and vice-versa. I just want the drag and drop from `#ula` to either `#ulb` or `#ulc`.

It is happening because of `connectWith: "#ulb, #ulc",` so it is connecting b with c as well. Any idea how can I achieve this?

```js
$("ul#a").on('click', 'li', function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass('selected');
  }
});

$("ul").sortable({
  connectWith: "#ulb, #ulc",
  delay: 150,
  revert: 0,
  helper: function(e, item) {
    if (!item.hasClass('selected')) {
      item.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    }
    var elements = item.parent().children('.selected').clone();
    item.data('multidrag', elements).siblings('.selected').remove();
    var helper = $('<li/>');
    return helper.append(elements);
  },
  stop: function(e, ui) {
    var elements = ui.item.data('multidrag');
    ui.item.after(elements).remove();
  }

});
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid Black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top
}

li {
  background-color: Azure;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted Gray
}

li.selected {
  background-color: GoldenRod
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="scripts/fieldChooser.js"></script>

<ul id="a">
  <li class="modifiable">One</li>
  <li class="modifiable">Two</li>
  <li class="modifiable">Three</li>
</ul>
<ul id="b">
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
</ul>
<ul id="c">
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please clarify, you want to Drag from A to B or C. B and C should not be able to drag to each other? But should be able to return to A?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve above is to check the `li` which is drag is under which `<ul>` get that `id` and see if that `li` is under `b` or `c` depending on this `cancel` drop using `$(this).sortable('cancel');` .

**Demo Code** :

```js
$("ul#a").on('click', 'li', function(e) {
  if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass('selected');
  }
});

$("ul").sortable({
  connectWith: "ul#b, ul#c",
  delay: 150,
  revert: 0,
  helper: function(e, item) {
 
    if (!item.hasClass('selected')) {
      item.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    }
    var elements = item.parent().children('.selected').clone();
    item.data('multidrag', elements).siblings('.selected').remove();
    var helper = $('<li/>');
    return helper.append(elements);
    
  },
  stop: function(e, ui) {
//checking the drag li is under which ul 
     if(($(e.target).closest('ul').attr('id')=="b" ) || ($(e.target).closest('ul').attr('id')=="c" ) ){
     //cancel sortable
  
        $(this).sortable('cancel');
           console.log("Sorry you cannot drap this")
     }else{
     
         var elements = ui.item.data('multidrag');
    ui.item.after(elements).remove();
     
     }
  }

});
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid Black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top
}

li {
  background-color: Azure;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted Gray
}

li.selected {
  background-color: GoldenRod
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="scripts/fieldChooser.js"></script>

<ul id="a">
  <li class="modifiable">One</li>
  <li class="modifiable">Two</li>
  <li class="modifiable">Three</li>
</ul>
<ul id="b">
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
</ul>
<ul id="c">
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise that you assign the `connectWith` option specifically for each list.

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $("ul#a").on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey) {
      $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass('selected');
    }
  });

  $("ul").sortable({
    delay: 150,
    revert: 0,
    helper: function(e, item) {
      if (!item.hasClass('selected')) {
        item.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
      }
      var elements = item.parent().children('.selected').clone();
      item.data('multidrag', elements).siblings('.selected').remove();
      var helper = $('<li/>');
      return helper.append(elements);
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
      var elements = ui.item.data('multidrag');
      ui.item.after(elements).remove();
    }
  });
  $("#a").sortable("option", "connectWith", "#b, #c");
  $("#b, #c").sortable("option", "connectWith", "#a");
});
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid Black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top
}

li {
  background-color: Azure;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted Gray
}

li.selected {
  background-color: GoldenRod
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="scripts/fieldChooser.js"></script>

<ul id="a">
  <li class="modifiable">One</li>
  <li class="modifiable">Two</li>
  <li class="modifiable">Three</li>
</ul>
<ul id="b">
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
</ul>
<ul id="c">
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

`#a` can drag to `#b` and `#c`. `#b` and `#c` can drag to `#a` . `#b` cannot drag to `#c` and `#c` cannot drag to `#b`.

Also, you are using `#ulb` and `#ulc` which do not exists. Either use `ul#b` or just `#b` as the selector.